# OpenCPU: Reuse results from previous session not working

Tags: r, opencpu

I would like to use `save_iris_as_csv` to save a *.csv* file. Then, call `catch_url_and_download` to download this *.csv* file using the session returned by `save_iris_as_csv`. However, the `catch_url_and_download` does not work, returning an error of

```
OpenCPU error HTTP 400
cannot open URL 'http://localhost:5656/ocpu/tmp/x06c27c3ac4/files/iris.csv'
```

The URL can be opened manually. It is just the second R function cannot open it.

Following is my javascript code.

```
ocpu.call("save_iris_as_csv",{},function(session){
    console.log("save_iris_as_csv is good.")
    console.log(session)
    console.log("trying to call catch_url_and_download.")
    ocpu.call("catch_url_and_download",{
        url:session.loc + "files/iris.csv"
    },function(session2){
        console.log(session2)
    }).fail(function(e){
        console.log("catch_url_and_download failed. Cannot open URL xxx.")
        alert(e.responseText)
    })
})
```

Following is my R codes.

```
save_iris_as_csv = function(){
  write.csv(iris,"iris.csv")
}
catch_url_and_download = function(url){
  download.file(url,"iris.csv")
}
```

I am using Windows OS.

Comment: If you get HTTP 400, the error message is in the body of the message.

Comment: Can you put this in an app (package) so we can easily reproduce it?

Comment: @Jeroen, Hi, it turns out the code works fine in the [cloud](https://slfan2013.ocpu.io/testingURL/www/). But it does not work locally. You could try my GitHub [demo R package](https://github.com/slfan2013/testingURL) locally. I am using Windows. I also tested it on Mac. They do not work. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that R is single threaded and hence the httpuv webserver (on which the opencpu single-user server is based) can only serve a single request at a time. In your example you've created a grid lock.

Your example makes a request to a function that then makes a second request to the *same webserver* using `download.file()`. This second requests gets queued by httpuv to be served when the first one completes, but obviously that never happens because `download.file()` just keeps waiting, until it times out.

This does not happen in the cloud server because apache2 is multi threaded.

To make it work with the single user server, you can make the first function save the data as an object in the workspace, and then the second function can access it via the session key. Or alternatively you could save it on disk or in a database or something, where the second function can access it. Anything that doesn't need a second http connection to the same local server.

Comment: thanks! How to save data as an object in the workspace exactly? By using `save(iris, file = "test.RData")`? If so, the second function still cannot read it using the session key because the url (`session.loc + "files/test.RData"`) cannot be loaded using `load()` function because of the single thread issue. I've uploaded my new code to the [Github](https://github.com/slfan2013/testingURL).

Comment: The best way is to have your target function return the R object. That way it will automatically be saved.